# How to enable Intellisense for VS Code & Angular

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

I wish to be able to right-click on the  tag and drill into the implementation or from inside the component implementation right-click > find all references > and drill back to this tag. Is there a VS Code extension or Setting that can help?

This picture shows the error when trying "Go to Implementations".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is Angular Follow Selector extension that you are looking for

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sanderledegen.angular-follow-selector

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Angular Language Service extension for VS Code by Angular. Check it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template